# How to set right value to 'all' in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I want use some syntax like `name=*` or `name=all` to avoid restrict the name field.

Because I just want to write one sql statement,e.g,`name=?`.If there is some syntax like above,just one sql above can do all situations.I just pass the name and call the sql statement on query.

But I don't find the real correct syntax, above is the pseudo-code,neither `*` nor `all` can do this.

Anybody can help?Thanks.

Comment: Hi, do you want to read from a table or may be update or insert into it? Can you share the query that you have which is not working?

Comment: Can you use something like `name=name`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i well understand  you want, with the same query, select records with a specific name or all the recors when a 'name' variable has no value.

If it's like that you can try with

```
name like '%'
```

when the variable 'name' has not value

Comment: Thanks your reply.That's what I wanted.@Massimo

Comment: @PhillipXT 's answer is also good.Thanks again for your help.